# Can't update my Bios

Tags: 64-bit, bios

I have a medion machine, model:PC MT 7 and type:MED 487G, which is running an msi motherboard.  I have installed Win7 x64 and have 4Gb Ram installed.  The operating system is using 3Gb but is aware there is 4Gb of RAM, I am guessing I need to update the motherboard bios to take advantage of the extra 1Gb.  Unfortuantely I can't find an update on the msi site and their automatic software update doesn't work.  Has anybody had an issue and managed to sort it out?  Or does anyone know where I can get the relevant update from?

Comment: Some of that RAM might also be used by the onboard graphics chipset, if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that a BIOS upgrade might not make your motherboard utilize the extra 1Gb of memory.  Usually, the memory modules have an SPD chip onboard (SPD = serial presence detect) which is used to tell the chipset the details about the memory on the module.   So, your OS is probably just reading/calculating the value from the memory SPD chip(s).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ralford, this is not a bios update problem, as the motherboard see's 4GB then it is working.

Try -

1) Go to start menu and search for "msconfig" and hit enter.

2) Go to the "Boot" tab and click on "Advanced Options".

3) Another menu should pop up. From there, you want to uncheck the box that says "Maximum memory"

4) It will ask you to restart your system. Restart it, and when it boots back up, it will use all your memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the checkbox is already unchecked

Comment: All Computers need RAM for graphics cards/sound cards e.t.c. I think this may be the problem.